# assert in C program

Tags: c

I got an error regarding assert

My program uses assert with an argument 0, for default case.

```
switch(choice)
{
    case OP_1:
        func_1();
        break;

    case OP_2:
        func_2();
        break;

    default:
        assert(0);
 }
```

how does assert work ?
Also it gives me error: undefined reference to assert.
I must specify that, program uses

```
#include <assert.h>
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Did you mean `#include <assert.h>`?

Comment: yes, you are correct !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assert is a macro. It is defined to nothing if NDEBUG is defined. You aren't including assert.h

Comment: its included in the program.
please check the updated program in question

Answer (score 0):

your source file is missing  the necessay include:

code:

```
#include <assert.h>
```